# Loop over (unknown) multidemensional array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an JavaScript array with an few elements **person** who have also multiple **friends**. These are also arrays from the elements **person**, which are also have **friends** and so on.

The dimensions are always different. I want to change the bool **isActive** of every person,
but how can I loop over this array?

I can not do nested loops like

```
for(int i=0; i<people.length; i++) {
    people[i].isActive = false;
    for(int j=0; j<people[i].friends.length; j++) {
        people[i].friends[j].isActive = false;
    }
}
```

Because I do not know how many loops I need every time. So is there a way to loop over every elements, if the dimension is not known?

```js
[{
    "_id": "6260127233256d2087fe5225",
    "isActive": false,
    "name": "Richard York",
    "friends": [{
        "id": "6260127247fbdbfc93bfe150",
        "isActive": false,
        "name": "Morales Wilkerson",
        "friends": [{
            "id": "62601272e138d5f44ac98eb3",
            "isActive": false,
            "name": "Anthony Cummings",
            "friends": [{
                "id": "62601272be338c3e6ad77953",
                "isActive": true,
                "name": "Burke Valentine",
                "friends": [{
                  "id": "626012722aefc063bd4d0b99",
                  "isActive": false,
                  "name": "Carey Patrick",
                  "friends": [{
                      "id": "626012727157cb04a275b55b",
                      "isActive": false,
                      "name": "Young Maynard"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "62601272e134281ce78eea6e",
                      "isActive": true,
                      "name": "Merle Mullins"
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
              {
                "id": "6260127287286f90a422cc90",
                "isActive": true,
                "name": "Wendi Glover",
                "friends": [{
                    "id": "62601272d28cd77a6e684116",
                    "isActive": false,
                    "name": "Megan Dorsey",
                    "friends": [{
                        "id": "626012720f017b59d0a95b62",
                        "isActive": false,
                        "name": "Mckinney Thomas"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "6260127297ae3d0cfda46200",
                        "isActive": false,
                        "name": "Ingram Cobb"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "62601272999d25fdb9ebbb57",
                    "isActive": false,
                    "name": "Ryan Byrd",
                    "friends": [{
                        "id": "62601272fad86888d4176dc4",
                        "isActive": false,
                        "name": "Hazel Pickett"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "62601272248b5c73be575635",
                        "isActive": false,
                        "name": "Farley Pollard"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "6260127217d6a7d57b4862e0",
            "isActive": true,
            "name": "Perry Reed",
            "friends": [{
                "id": "62601272164e0f07189938fb",
                "isActive": false,
                "name": "Janis Petersen",
                "friends": [{
                    "id": "626012729fe5f80251ee27fe",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "name": "Avila Hartman",
                    "friends": [{
                        "id": "6260127232df76fe2fe47acf",
                        "isActive": false,
                        "name": "Bette Conner"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "62601272118980db757f4a72",
                        "isActive": false,
                        "name": "Camacho Phillips"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "626012722693c166ff849403",
                    "isActive": false,
                    "name": "Bright Leblanc",
                    "friends": [{
                        "id": "62601272278055f57871baf8",
                        "isActive": true,
                        "name": "Ballard Nichols"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": "62601272501bc27806a90c91",
                        "isActive": false,
                        "name": "Tracey Carver"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": "6260127235b047abe049eca4",
                "isActive": true,
                "name": "Belinda Harrington",
                "friends": [{
                  "id": "6260127281d798b10bd24fa7",
                  "isActive": false,
                  "name": "Potter Harris",
                  "friends": [{
                      "id": "626012726266024252195d30",
                      "isActive": false,
                      "name": "Briggs Shannon"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "62601272246e464e4c0f226d",
                      "isActive": false,
                      "name": "Haney Miranda"
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "626012720570d38269ba11e2",
        "isActive": true,
        "name": "Marci Wooten",
        "friends": [{
            "id": "62601272df0a520e49d4b931",
            "isActive": true,
            "name": "Jeanette Peters",
            "friends": [{
              "id": "626012726ed027fe9de5f017",
              "isActive": true,
              "name": "Joy Huber",
              "friends": [{
                  "id": "62601272e91904cb3c71cc86",
                  "isActive": true,
                  "name": "Barber Franklin",
                  "friends": [{
                      "id": "6260127248c041a83be9ea51",
                      "isActive": false,
                      "name": "Patrick Vang"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "62601272338c7be47b531034",
                      "isActive": false,
                      "name": "Lynn Howell"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id": "626012722bb9de756e4beafd",
                  "isActive": true,
                  "name": "Stone Burke",
                  "friends": [{
                      "id": "62601272b0e6e80019a26f87",
                      "isActive": false,
                      "name": "Holloway Stout"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "626012726b20a4409b113bf3",
                      "isActive": true,
                      "name": "Ayala Cochran"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }]
          },
          {
            "id": "62601272ef3618062f81223b",
            "isActive": true,
            "name": "Larsen Garrison",
            "friends": [{
                "id": "6260127205a58271b195c94b",
                "isActive": true,
                "name": "Gray Long",
                "friends": [{
                  "id": "6260127291eb1b18573c72a9",
                  "isActive": false,
                  "name": "Carmella Lancaster",
                  "friends": [{
                      "id": "62601272dc9a0cecaa4201f4",
                      "isActive": true,
                      "name": "Natasha Hendricks"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "62601272ff294c758fda66c1",
                      "isActive": false,
                      "name": "Aimee Ramos"
                    }
                  ]
                }]
              },
              {
                "id": "6260127290348d6146db7c6d",
                "isActive": false,
                "name": "Molly Callahan",
                "friends": [{
                  "id": "62601272ddfe0bab1769a256",
                  "isActive": true,
                  "name": "Kellie Mayer",
                  "friends": [{
                    "id": "626012721da1a045f0d19000",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "name": "Angelica Whitehead"
                  }]
                }]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "62601272903aac279685fa5f",
    "isActive": true,
    "name": "Roman Morris",
    "friends": [{
        "id": "62601272191c0d0b8538e377",
        "isActive": false,
        "name": "Maxwell Kennedy",
        "friends": [{
          "id": "626012728496c147c85d8093",
          "isActive": false,
          "name": "Mullins Ross",
          "friends": [{
              "id": "6260127245a1df0453eadc69",
              "isActive": false,
              "name": "Elisa Mccray",
              "friends": [{
                  "id": "6260127289ba07412d246545",
                  "isActive": false,
                  "name": "Mckenzie Bartlett",
                  "friends": [{
                    "id": "62601272ef239d452a3f8356",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "name": "Mathews Barron"
                  }]
                },
                {
                  "id": "62601272e950eac38c139618",
                  "isActive": false,
                  "name": "Dickson Hutchinson",
                  "friends": [{
                      "id": "62601272a4121c14b1e8bc46",
                      "isActive": true,
                      "name": "Tyler Mccarty"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "6260127233eec33ffeb4a428",
                      "isActive": false,
                      "name": "Melisa Foley"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": "62601272a2bcf03a4fadbb6f",
              "isActive": false,
              "name": "Davidson Emerson",
              "friends": [{
                  "id": "62601272a283582ca662d9d7",
                  "isActive": true,
                  "name": "Alvarez Jenkins",
                  "friends": [{
                      "id": "6260127236c2e56e91081b63",
                      "isActive": true,
                      "name": "Coleman Clements"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "62601272a229a19e2c1d5b20",
                      "isActive": false,
                      "name": "Leah Watkins"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id": "6260127211c171775a7e48a9",
                  "isActive": true,
                  "name": "Erma Mcpherson",
                  "friends": [{
                      "id": "6260127251cc951b1181f0d4",
                      "isActive": true,
                      "name": "Melanie Mendoza"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "626012722c7a0d7f35a8dc06",
                      "isActive": false,
                      "name": "Desiree Cooley"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }]
      },
      {
        "id": "6260127298326565f0861478",
        "isActive": false,
        "name": "Karen Joyner",
        "friends": [{
          "id": "62601272fb6aa3050f721331",
          "isActive": false,
          "name": "Silvia Summers",
          "friends": [{
              "id": "62601272c16247da0950c03b",
              "isActive": true,
              "name": "Mary Duncan",
              "friends": [{
                  "id": "6260127269aaa4c7fd1fed0d",
                  "isActive": false,
                  "name": "Bender Fischer",
                  "friends": [{
                    "id": "626012722e1893e8ed26458c",
                    "isActive": false,
                    "name": "Carlson Owen"
                  }]
                },
                {
                  "id": "6260127250a0675ba7f36d46",
                  "isActive": false,
                  "name": "Richards Orr",
                  "friends": [{
                      "id": "6260127228816bffee65fd5e",
                      "isActive": true,
                      "name": "Best Carson"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "626012729575b6c7495830ea",
                      "isActive": false,
                      "name": "Fuller Robbins"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": "626012728bacdb8d66e69236",
              "isActive": false,
              "name": "Goodwin Hale",
              "friends": [{
                "id": "626012724f9ac8f4819b12c7",
                "isActive": true,
                "name": "Flossie Humphrey",
                "friends": [{
                    "id": "6260127228e2ccaf5d961fcd",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "name": "Ginger Baker"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": "6260127255748930da881a57",
                    "isActive": false,
                    "name": "Odonnell Calhoun"
                  }
                ]
              }]
            }
          ]
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=iterate+recursively+object+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You should look into a _recursive_ approach then. (Or, if this is a data structure of your own making - maybe structure it differently to begin with? Depending on what you actually want to do with this, I am not sure this "nesting" is actually helpful, and whether a flat structure might not make more sense.)